# How to use a value as a variable?

Tags: powershell, office365

I'm creating a Powershell script that can be used to convert a mailbox to a shared mailbox in Office 365. But first I want to check if the mailbox has status as Shared or not.

If I run this command I get a answer:

```
Get-Mailbox -identity $user | select-object IsShared

IsShared
--------
   False
```

So I want to use this value that in this case is False.

```
$user = Read-Host -Prompt "What mailbox to check?"
$status = Get-Mailbox -identity $user | select-object IsShared 

If ($status -eq "false") 
    {Write-Host "$user status is NOT shared"}
Else 
    {write-host "$user status is shared"}
```

Problem is that I only get the last message in return. Even if I change this code:

```
If ($status -eq true)
```

So obviously there is something I need to change. But what?

Comment: It's not a string `"true"`/`"false"` (note quotes) it's a boolean `$true`/`$false` so you need to check it like this: `$status -eq $false`

Comment: ok thank you for your input. I changed it now removed the quotes and added the $-sign in front:

If ($status -eq $false) 

But I still get the same output. and not the right output

Comment: You will have another issue. You need to expand the value from the object first before you do your comparison. `...| select-object -ExpandProperty IsShared`

Comment: @Matt Thanks, that seems to done the trick

Answer (score 2):

Even though it just shows an output of `False`, it's not a string `"true"` / `"false"` (note quotes) it's a [boolean](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2006/12/24/boolean-values-and-operators/) `$true`/`$false`

To check `IsShared`, rather than using `Select-Object` (would also need `ExpandProperty` to work correctly), you can use `$status.IsShared` to refer to just that property. This leaves the original object intact should you wish to use any of it's other properties later in your code.

(Small [blog post](https://www.codykonior.com/2013/03/26/powershell-how-to-show-all-of-an-objects-properties-and-values/) on object properties and values.)

Which when put together gives:

```
$user = Read-Host -Prompt "What mailbox to check?"
$status = Get-Mailbox -identity $user

if ($status.IsShared -eq $false) { Write-Host "$user status is NOT shared" }
else { Write-Host "$user status is shared" }
```

You could also flip the `if` as it will check for `$true` by default:

```
if ($status.IsShared) { Write-Host "$user status is shared" }
else { Write-Host "$user status is NOT shared" }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to replace `Get-Mailbox -identity $user | select-object IsShared` with `Get-Mailbox -identity $user | select -ExpandProperty IsShared`
The former one is not exactly returning false while the latter one returns false.